# Aurelia validation errors not displayed when validation initialized on attached

Tags: aurelia

I want to show invalid input fields when the view is shown.

I have validation rules setup in a separate class (UserValidation) with one function (initValidatorOn).

```
export class UserValidation {

    public _validation: Validation;

    constructor(validation: Validation) {
        this._validation = validation;
    }

    initValidatorOn(user: UserDto): ValidationGroup {
           return this._validation.on(user, null)
                .ensure('name').isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

Everything works for this setup.

```
export class User {
    public validationGroup : ValidationGroup;
    public userValidation : UserValidation;
    public user : UserDto;
    constructor(uv: UserValidation) {
        this.userValidation = uv;
        //this code works here and in activate method
        this.validationGroup = this.userValidation.initValidatorOn(this.user);
    }

    attached() {
        this.validationGroup.validate();
    }
}
```

As I said before, the above works. But sometimes the object that I need to validate I not available in constructor or in activate function so I need to initialize validation in attached function. When I do that, my view no longer shows validation errors until I update the value in input. 
So, this doesn't work

```
attached() {
    this.validationGroup = this.userValidation.initValidatorOn(this.user);
    //no validation errors displayed on the view
    this.validationGroup.validate();
}
```

Can someone explain why errors aren't displayed on the view after I call validate when I initialize validationGroup in attached function?
Thank you.